# Gson to pojo serialization of inner class

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to take a json and convert it into a POJO using Gson's ability. I got it working with the serialized class as a class in a separate package, but now I am trying to get the serialized class to be an inner class of the class which is calling it, kind of like how I have depicted below.

```
public class A {
    private final Gson gson;

    public A() {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
    }

    public void foo(String json){
        B b = gson.fromJson(json, B.class);
    }

    public static class B {
         private String bar;

         public String getBar(){
             return bar;
         }
    }
}
```

Sample JSON:

```
{"bar": "test"}
```

This setup returns null values for the inner class variables; in this case, just bar. I've made sure the json being passed in matches the names of variables in Class B, in this example. Additionally, I have experimented around with making the inner class non-static and private with no success. To my understanding it needs to be a static class in order for it to be serialized using gson. Is there anything blatantly obvious that I am doing wrong that you can see?

Comment: Could it be you're missing the setter for *bar*? Can you post a sample JSON?

Comment: Didn't think it was that since these are the exact classes I had when it was working in a separate package as opposed to an inner class. Went ahead and tried it anyway and did not have any luck. I'll edit my post to add a sample JSON.

Comment: Why do you have `gson` as a parameter to the `foo` function when all that happens is that it's immediately overwritten?

Comment: I actually have that happening elsewhere in my code, I merely added that to show what it is being set to since as I found with an earlier problem, it must have the `serializeNulls()` method in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I imagine this is a common issue, now that I've run into it twice. The issue was in the JSON string being passed in. I copied and pasted the JSON from somewhere into the command line. As a result, the quotations weren't being registered as valid quotation marks. It was `“` as opposed to `"`. The second is what is registered as a quotation mark. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is somewhere else. Most probably the `String` or the `Gson` you pass is configured the wrong way. I pasted the exact same code and it works fine for me:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new A().foo("{\"bar\": \"test\"}");
    }

    public static class A {
        private final Gson gson;

        public A() {
            gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        }

        public void foo(String json){
            B b = gson.fromJson(json, B.class);
            System.out.println(b);
        }

        public static class B {
            private String bar;

            public String getBar(){
                return bar;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "B{bar='" + bar + '\'' +
                        '}';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Inner classes are *supposed* to work so the problem is elsewhere. This will print out:

> B{bar='test'}

Comment: In the code I actually have, as opposed to the simplified version I made for the question, `gson` is set in the constructor of `class A` in this case. I will edit my question to more accurately reflect this -- I didn't think that simplification would be a concern.

Comment: My answer still stands. See the update. You have a problem elsewhere probably you pass the wrong string to `foo`.

Comment: Just figured it out. Was something to do with the string I was passing in -- I imagine this is a common issue, I'll post my answer in a sec.

Comment: You can upvote / accept if the answer was useful for you.

Comment: I did! Unfortunately I have less than 15 reputation currently since my account is largely not active for posting and answering so it won't show up.